# Adding a function to a prototype does not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a function to prototype like this

```
function Dog(name, breed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
}

function barkWithMe() {
    console.log("woof woof i am " + this.name);
}
Dog.prototype.bark = barkWithMe();

var snoopy = new Dog();
snoopy.bark();
```

But it displays an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: snoopy.bark is not a function
```

Please tell me where am I wrong. Thanks.

Comment: you are executing the function and assigning the return value, not assigning the function itself

Comment: Debug your program. Please a breakpoint on the `Dog.prototype.bark =` line. Step over it. You will notice that the message was logged--which would alert you that something odd was happening. Then you would examine the value of `Dog.prototype.bark`, and find that it is `undefined`--yet another clue. It shouldn't be much of a leap from there to figuring out that you were inadvertently calling `barkWithMe` instead of just assigning it to the prototype.

Comment: The error message has told you everything, `snoopy.bark is not a function` because it's `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line evaluates the function and sets the return value `undefined` to `Dog.prototype.bark`:

```
Dog.prototype.bark = barkWithMe();
```

Change it to:

```
Dog.prototype.bark = barkWithMe;
```